# How to configure container level form based authentication with login page shared between multipe web apps

Tags: tomcat, authentication, single-sign-on, forms-authentication

I've been looking into how to best configure form based authentication in Tomcat and found quite a few examples on how to configure SSO. However all the examples I found seem to face the same problem in an environment with many war files deployed; namely that the login jsp lives within each war. This is counter to any coding principles where one would want to reuse the same login page for all wars and in case the login page changes only change it in one single place.

Is there a way to configure form based authentication in Tomcat where war 1 and war 2 are protected by a login page which only lives in war 3?

Comment: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Tomcat+Container+Authentication

Comment: Thanks Neil  
  
Javasig is an awesome group; I used to attend their meetings back in the days.  
  
I'm a little sceptic about this cas implementation though. I had a quick look and couldn't find any documentaton yet on how to install and configure a cas server. Also the wiki only mentions compatibility to older Tomcat versions 6 and 7 but not the latest 8 and 9 version. Regardless I will have a go at it and see if I can get it to work.  
  
In my opinion it would be so much easier for Tomcat to additionally support redirects to a login page instead of only forwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a thorough solution to this problem you might want to look up SSO systems (Single Sign On). Some names (product names as well as protocols, I'm just mixing them) are OpenAM, CAS, Shibboleth, SAML. Just to name a few. These can even live outside of your single tomcat and even on a different domain name - but deployment is a bit harder than just deploying a different WAR file.

Note that tomcat enables you to configure different Realms for each web application - you'd have to make sure that you're not configuring a mess for yourself.

For a tomcat-only solution, you can use the [SingleSignOn Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Single%20Sign%20On). However, as you see in that documentation, it will use the current webapplication's login page - which is exactly what you're asking for not to use.

Choose your poison: Multiple Login Pages on tomcat WAR files, or setup and maintenance of a separate application

Comment: It would be such a simple change for tomcat to also support a redirect besides only a forward in the FormAuthenticator's forwardToLoginPage method.

Comment: By looking at sources I found that glassfish at some point made a change to their tomcat clone to also support a sendRedirect which makes sense to me. 

I've used a few external SSO products and most of them work great but I find them to be such a huge added complexity just for a missing redirect. I'm actually wondering that not more people have complained about this over the years.

Comment: Right now I'm contemplating about which poison to swallow...

a) Modify FormAuthenticator, compile it and stick it in the classpath before catalina.jar (drawback are that this may break with the next tomcat upgrade)

b) Subclass FormAuthenticator forwardToLoginMethod and modify Authenticators.properties to add a new auth-method (e.g. MY_FORM, again this may break during the next upgrade)

c) Implement an external SSO (added complexity)

d) Copy login page into each war (reduced maintainability)

Haven't made up my mind yet...